# default browser path in different OS

Tags: cross-browser, browser

I need the browser path that depend on different OS .

For example ,
in Win7 , Firefox's path might be 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Chrome might be
%APPDATA%\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

---

I am developing a Eclipse plug-in ,which help user launch browser for specific url in a project, it's going to speed up the web developing .

Sometimes we need to use chrome/firefox/IE8/safari to test web page ,
so that's why I am developing such a plug-in.

My user could set up the browser path manually now , 
and I could let them use default browser as first one. (it's already done.)

If I could have the paths in different OS/path , 
I could check if there's existing those file and setup the path by default.
(Just like what selenium-rc does.)

If there's any one have the information for default browser path?

The difficult part is there's too many OS and too many browsers,
hope you could help me to get the information.

Any browser that running on PC is welcome , 
like opera,IE,chrome,firefox,safari...etc

Answer (score 1):

Query the [default application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144154%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the HTTP protocol. Use the COM interface if possible.

Comment: That's not what I need. I need the path , I have to launch many different browsers. Not only default one , and I could open the default browser already.